# Sort the list of custom object w.r.t. a data member

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have a List of applications in which each entity represent a custom object.

```
List<String> Applications = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I have my Application class like this:

```
public Class Application
{
    private String ApplicationName;
    private int Priority
}
```

I need to sort Applications w.r.t. Priority. Note that Priority can contain only three will values, i.e. 1, 2 and 3 for High, Medium and Low respectively.

I have implemented Comparator to sort the list like this:

```
Collections.sort(this.Applications, new Comparator<Application>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Application App1, Application App2)
    {
        return App1.Priority.compareTo(App2.Priority);
    }
});
```

But the compiler gives me this error:

```
Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int
```

Comment: The main problem is that `int` is a primitive type, not a class, and there are **NO** methods to invoke from a primitive type. [LouisWasserman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21915358/1065197) explains how to solve this.

Comment: As a note, Java convention is that variable and method names should start with a lowercase letter: `app1.priority`. Following this convention will make your code much easier for others to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Java 7, then replace

```
return IA1.Priority.compareTo(IA2.Priority);
```

with

```
return Integer.compare(IA1.Priority, IA2.Priority);
```

...otherwise, you'll have to replace it with

```
if (IA1.Priority < IA2.Priority) {
  return -1;
} else if (IA1.Priority == IA2.Priority) {
  return 0;
} else {
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: or simply ```return IA2.Priority - IA1.Priority;```

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj that may cause an overflow.

Comment: luiggi-mendoza: That's right, but I think the Priority of the app won't be a very large and negative number. I agree it's not a very good advice :)

Comment: @louis: As I am developing for Android. Therefore, Your first replacement gives me this error: `Call requires API level 19 (current min is 8)`

Comment: @luiggi: As I mentioned, Priority will contain only there numbers. 1, 2 and 3. Nothing else.

Comment: @Faheem If the priority is really restricted to the values 1, 2, and 3, it might make sense to make it an enum instead. Type-safe, and you'd get the `compareTo` for free.

Comment: The second solution worked perfectly for me. I'll have chrylis's trick up my sleeve for future.